# JCraft SFTP for eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, sftp

I've been using for the last 6 years [JCraft's SFTP plugin](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-sftp/).
It's quite simple to use and the only problem i ever had with it is that it doesn't know how to delete recursivly files and folders (it tries to delete folders before files).

Today i tried to update eclipse to Luna and I can't seem to install this plugin anymore.
I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.jcraft.eclipse.team.sftp 0.0.4, action=).
Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.jcraft.eclipse.team.sftp 0.0.4.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: Raise bug to the authors tracker.

Comment: The project hasn't been maintained for over 6 years and my previous attempts to report a bug were never answered.

Comment: Try to install in other Eclipse e.g. Kepler to ensure it is not network error. But for future getting sources is what is needed for the project to have chances to live on.

Comment: just tried on Kepler, works fine :) it's really a Luna problem.

Comment: Last chance is to raise bug on Eclipse bugzilla, maybe they can answer what exactly was changed in Luna and whether can be workaround for such error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message "Failed to prepare partial IU" I found this thread: https://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/issues/detail?id=47

The suggested workaround is to install the "Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support", which adds support for "running old Eclipse plugins that are not proper OSGi bundles."

Comment: Your link points to a 404 not Found page. Will test that asap.

Comment: This works like a charm ! Could install my plugin on Eclipse Mars ! Finally will be able to upgrade.

Comment: As of eclipse neon, this doesn't seem to work anymore. It looks like they completely dropped API 2.0 support

Answer (score 0):

You can use Remote System Explorer (RSE) to replace the sftp plugin. It has sftp capabilities (use ssh connection) and allows you to synchronize files between local and server storage

Comment: Thanks gerald. I've tried that but I have [the following problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305331/eclipse-rse-synchronization-keeping-sublcipse)

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled to get JCraft installed and then I discovered that Remote System Explorer (RSE) comes already installed in Eclipse Luna in the Java EE version but it may be baked into other versions of Eclipse as well.  All I had to do was navigate to Window > Open Perspective > Other... > Remote System Explorer.

Once in the Remote Systems perspective, you will see links to your local files.  To create a SSH connection to a remote server (even if it is in the same location as you but requires SSH protocol), just right-click anywhere in that Remote Systems tab and choose New > Connection and then under the General folder, select SSH Only.  Fill out the host name or IP address.

If successful, the server will appear as a folder under the Local one.  Attempt to navigate below the server's 'SFTP Files' folder and you will be prompted for your user ID and password on that remote server.  Say yes to the prompt about trusting the certificate and you are good to go.  Your remote files will appear in the file explorer type of GUI in that Remote Systems perspective.

Switch back to your regular local environment in any other perspective in the upper right corner of the Eclipse window just as you normally would.